# Init event in global.asax not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net

My init event is not firing.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Reflection" %>

<script RunAt="server">

  public void Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Init();
    }

 public void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
    }

 public void Application_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Init();
    }
</script>
```

As you can see I have written several different overloads but none of them fires. I am totally confused. The other events like `Application_Start` etc do fire.

What am I missing? I am using Asp.Net 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application_Init` event is fired when an application initializes the first time. After initialize, this event will not fire. So maybe your application already initialized. You can close virtual host which otomatically opened when debug start and re-start to debug.

**Also its method signature is that:**

```
protected void Application_Init();
```

Remove all events trying from your code in question.

**Just write this:**

```
<%@ Application Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Reflection" %>

<script RunAt="server">

 public void Application_Init()
    {
      //Do something...
    }

</script>
```